# iOS Universal Link: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, applinks

I believe this is the reason why Applink is not working for us.

When we try accessing our domain name (which has Universal Link correctly setup) we get this error :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
Try this: 
(1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
(2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x1512872d0 h=--& v=--& AppLinkBanner:0x14fd55c20.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14fd4c560 UILabel:0x14fd4c0a0'My App Name'.lastBaseline == AppLinkBanner:0x14fd55c20.top + 20   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14fd4cea0 UILabel:0x14fd4c860'Open in the My App Name ...'.firstBaseline == UILabel:0x14fd4c0a0'My App Name'.lastBaseline + 16   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14fd4d080 AppLinkBanner:0x14fd55c20.bottom == UILabel:0x14fd4c860'Open in the My App Name ...'.lastBaseline + 8   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x14fd4cea0 UILabel:0x14fd4c860'Open in the My App Name ...'.firstBaseline == UILabel:0x14fd4c0a0'My App Name'.lastBaseline + 16   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Applink is correctly setup as the app opens when I click on a link on notes or calendar.

Anyone knows what this means and how to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm pretty confident that has nothing to do with your app's universal linking not working. Are you attempting to link to your app or are you attempting to link out to another app?

Comment: I stopped trying using Universal links for identity providers (facebook / apple). We're implementing an in-app browser for native devices now